# how to select the max valid enclosing json in vim

Tags: json, vim

Assume the current caret is inside a json object in vim, how can I select the maximum valid enclosing json?
I literally don't have much idea about how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`vap`

This select all paragraph, in many cases this is what you need.

Comment: If I have a json object embedded in other text, it wouldn't select ONLY the json. So it wouldn't work in this case.